# Updating UXSE badges to be more accessible

Tags: feature-request

I noticed that this question has been asked quite some time ago, and should be considered a feature request: [What can we do to make UX Stack Exchange badges accessible?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/130881/what-can-we-do-to-make-ux-stack-exchange-badges-accessible)

There were some good options suggested for making these achievement badges more user friendly and improving the accessibility, and many other sites have already adopted better practices so there's no reason why UXSE should not also be using best practices.